# symfony Error: Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got '.'

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a query that looks for results obtained from a variable in the controller.

```
$category = $request->request->get('category');

$catContent = $em->getRepository('PublicartelAppBundle:Content')->findByCategory($category);

public function findByCategory($category)
    {
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();

        $dql = 'SELECT c FROM Publicartel\AppBundle\Entity\Content c';

        if (!is_null($category)) {
            $dql .= " WHERE c.categories.name = category";
        }

        $query = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery($dql)
            ->setHydrationMode(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);

        if (!is_null($category)) {
            $query->setParameter('category', $category);
        }

        return $query->getResult();
    }
```

But when I run the action for the query I get this error occurs:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 71: Error: Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got '.'
```

SELECT c FROM Publicartel\AppBundle\Entity\Content c WHERE c.categories.name = category

$categories is an atribute for the entity content.

```
class Content
{
private $categories;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->categories = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

public function addCategories(\Publicartel\AppBundle\Entity\Category $categories)
    {
        $this->categories[] = $categories;

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeCategories(\Publicartel\AppBundle\Entity\Category $categories)
    {
        $this->categories->removeElement($categories);
    }

    public function setCategories(\Publicartel\AppBundle\Entity\Category $categories = null)
    {
        $this->categories = $categories;

        return $this;
    }
    public function getCategories()
    {
        return $this->categories;
    }
}
```

The strange thing is that when I get get the variable , the error does not appear.

```
$category = $request->query->get('category');
```

Comment: Did you misplace the `:` in your query before "category": `WHERE c.categories.name = :category` ?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot reference subobject this way:

```
SELECT c FROM Publicartel\AppBundle\Entity\Content c WHERE c.categories.name = :category
```

You need to `JOIN` prior to that and use alias of that joined entity. Something like this:

```
SELECT c, cat FROM Publicartel\AppBundle\Entity\Content c JOIN c.categories cat WHERE cat.name = :category
```

Now, either use `LEFT JOIN` or just `JOIN` and it should work.

Comment: I edit the reply, the problem persists, one that is located in another line but with the same message.